# Play animation to each view sequentially with a method call

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation

The fragment has several CardViews. I've made an utility class that contains the next method:

```
public void applyAnimationToEachView(@NonNull Collection<View> views,
                                     @NonNull AnimationSet animationSet,
                                         long offset,
                                         boolean offsetSequentially) {
        int i = 0;
        for (View view: views) {
            view.setAnimation(animationSet);
            if (offsetSequentially)
                view.getAnimation().setStartOffset(offset * i);
            else view.getAnimation().setStartOffset(offset);
            view.getAnimation().start();
            i++;
        }
    }
```

I call the method this way:

```
override fun onHiddenChanged(hidden: Boolean) {
        if (!hidden) AnimationManager().applyAnimationToEachView(
                visibleCards as Collection<View>,
                getAnimationSet(),
                100,
                true)
    }
```

However, when I call the method, it sums up the offsets and shows the animation inconsequentially. When I do the same thing inside of the fragment, it works as intended:

```
        var i : Long = 0
        if (!hidden)
            for (cardView in visibleCards) {
                cardView.animation = getAnimationSet()
                cardView.animation.startOffset = 100 * i
                i = i.inc()
            }
```

What's the reason behind this behavior? And can I somehow hide this functionality inside of my utility class?

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're passing the same instance of `AnimationSet` to each `View` and then retrieve it with `view.getAnimation()`. Thus its start offset increases on each loop iteration. In order to make it work, you'll need to create a new `Animation` for each `View`.